# How to select dynamic column in Xamarin forms SQL Lite

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I using Xamarin forms. I would like to select my dynamic column using SQL Lite Query but I got an error.

Here is My model :

```
public class MyWords
{

[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
public int ID { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
public Guid MyId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "languagevalue1")]
public string LanguageValue1 { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "languagevalue2")]
public string LanguageValue2 { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "languagevaluecombine")]
public string LanguageValueCombine { get { return LanguageValue1 + "  " + Separator + "  " + LanguageValue2; } }

}
```

I would like to get the value of the column "languagevaluecombine" but I have an error.

Here is how I query my column "languagevaluecombine"  table :

```
var ListCombine = conn.QueryAsync<MyWords>("select DISTINCT languagevaluecombine from MyWords ");
```

Here is the error that got :

```
SQLite.SQLiteException has been thrown
no such column: languagevaluecombine
```

But When I try with the column "languagevalue2" I works as it is not a dynamic columns

Thanks for your help

Comment: A SQL query will execute against what is in the database, not what is in your c# classes. If there is no column by that name it will never work.

Comment: You can use `Table` to load your data into a C# class and then query by that property

Comment: @Jason Please do you have an example ?

Comment: You can try to concat two coumns like this: `var ListCombine = conn.QueryAsync<MyWords>("select  (LanguageValue1   || ' ' || LanguageValue2 ) as languagevaluecombine from MyWords ");`